# Given a number N, find the smallest even number E such that E > N

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a number N, find the smallest even number E such that E > N and digits in N and E are same.

```
   Print NONE otherwise.
    Sample:
Case1
    Input
    N = 34722641 
    Output
    E = 34724126
Case2
    Input
    N = 8234961
    Output
    E = 8236194 (instead of 8236149)
```

My second case passed first case i am getting wrong output

```
public static int nextDigit(int number) {
String num = String.valueOf(number);
int stop = 0;
char[] orig_chars = null;
char[] part1 = null;
char[] part2 = null;
orig_chars = num.toCharArray();

for (int i = orig_chars.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    String previous = orig_chars[i - 1] + "";
    String next = orig_chars[i] + "";
    if (Integer.parseInt(previous) < Integer.parseInt(next))
{
    if (Integer.parseInt(previous) % 2 == 0) {

        String partString1 = "";
        String partString2 = "";
        for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++) {
            partString1 = partString1.concat(orig_chars[j] + "");
        }
        part1 = partString1.toCharArray();
        for (int k = i; k < orig_chars.length; k++) {
            partString2 = partString2.concat(orig_chars[k] + "");
        }
        part2 = partString2.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(part2);
        for (int l = 0; l < part2.length; l++) {
            char temp = '0';
            if (part2[l] > part1[i - 1]) {
                temp = part1[i - 1];
                part1[i - 1] = part2[l];
                part2[l] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < part2.length; m++) {
            char replace = '0';
            if (part2[m] % 2 == 0) {
                replace = part2[m];
                for (int n = m; n < part2.length - 1; n++) {
                    part2[n] = part2[n + 1];
                }
                part2[part2.length - 1] = replace;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.print(part1);
        System.out.println(part2);
        System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
     System.out.println("NONE");

  return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How many digits N have? Less than 10?

Comment: Your second case looks like the right output to me. It fits the condition of being even and greater than the input...

Answer (score 2):

First idea was to generate the next permutation until an even one is found. This works well for small inputs or when an even permutation is nearby, but badly for large inputs such as 2135791357913579 where many permutations have to happen "to the right" before the sole even digit is moved into place.

גלעד ברקן suggested a patch which with minor adjustment provides a superior algorithm.

- As with the next permutation algorithm, we find indices i and j with i < j where the ith digit is less than the jth digit. When we swap those digits, this makes a larger number then N.
- Apply the additional constraint that there is an even number to the right of i after the swap.
- Take the largest such even number to the right of the index (might not be the one you just swapped), move it to the end. This guarantees evenness.
- Then sort the remaining digits in between in ascending order. This provides the smallest permutation available.

The algorithm in Clojure could be written as follows. I tried to stick to a fairly imperative style. See if you can translate.

```
(defn num->digits [n] (mapv #(Character/getNumericValue %) (str n)))

(defn digits->num [v] (when (seq v) (read-string (apply str v))))

(defn swap 
  "Swap elements at index i and j in vector v"
  [v i j]
  (assoc (assoc v i (v j)) j (v i)))

(defn find-max-where
  "Find index i in vector v such that (v i) is the largest satisfying pred"
  [pred v] 
  (first 
    (reduce-kv 
      (fn [[k m] i x] 
        (if (and m (> m x)) 
          [k m] 
          (if (pred x) [i x] [k m]))) 
      [nil nil] 
      v)))

(defn next-even-perm [v] 
  (->>
    (for [j (range (count v))
          i (range j) 
          :when (< (v i) (v j))
          :let [v (swap v i j)
                k (find-max-where even? (vec (subvec v (inc i))))]
          :when k
          :let [v (swap v (+ (inc i) k) (dec (count v)))]] 
      (concat (subvec v 0 (inc i)) 
              (sort (subvec v (inc i) (dec (count v)))) 
              [(peek v)])) 
    (map vec) sort first))

(defn next-even-num [n] (-> n num->digits next-even-perm digits->num))
```

Provided examples:

```
 (next-even-num 34722641) 
 ;=> 34724126

 (next-even-num 8234961)
 ;=> 8236194

 (next-even-num 4321) 
 ;=> nil (no solution)
```

Hard cases for previous algorithm

```
(time (next-even-num 2135791357913579))
; "Elapsed time: 1.598446 msecs"
;=> 3111335557779992

(time (next-even-num 13244351359135913))
; "Elapsed time: 1.713501 msecs"
;=> 13245111333355994

(time (next-even-num 249999977777555553333311111N))
; "Elapsed time: 1.874579 msecs"
;=> 251111133333555577777999994N
```

Latest edit fixes problem where we were always wanting to swap with an even number moving right instead of just having any even number to the right whether or not it was involved in the swap. For example, the following failed in the previous edit, now fixed.

```
(next-even-num 1358) 
;=> 1538
```

Comment: Note: This will probably perform well for small inputs and on average. But, for large inputs, some arrangements of digits will cause a prohibitively large number of permutations to be searched before finding an even one, e.g. 2135791357913579.

Comment: The only time this algorithm might be slow, as you suggest, is when the nearest even digit is more than 10 or so digits to the left. But in that case, the answer is straightforward - place the next higher digit to its right directly to its right, move the even digit all the way to the right, and sort the digits in between ascending to the right. Sound correct?

Comment: @גלעדברקן IMO, the sort will not work, as this problem also require the created number must be larger than N, a sort will not fulfill this easily

Comment: @גלעדברקן That sounds close. You'd want to find the rightmost index at which there is an even number with a larger number to the right and choose smallest such larger number. Then swap those numbers. This makes a larger number than N. Then take the *largest* even number to the right (might not be the one you just swapped), move it to the end. This guarantees evenness. Then sort the remaining digits in between in ascending order (smallest permutation available. If correct, you just always do this rather than in special cases (i.e. abandon the next-permutation algorithm).

Comment: @A.Webb actually, the not happy case will always happen when there are a larger amount of odd digits at the end of N, which require your solution to generate all permutations for the last odd digits , for example : N is 132443513591359.

Comment: @PhamTrung Yes, I agree, I noted 2135791357913579 as a bad example. If we use the algorithm sketched by גלעדברקן and myself directly above on 2135791357913579, we'd immediately pick 2 at the first index as the only even candidate, find 3 as smallest larger number to the right and get 3125791357913579. Then we'd place the smallest even number to the right of the first index at the end: 3157913579135792 and sort the digits in between 3111335557779992. This looks plausibly correct. Can you test against your dp algorithm?

Comment: I think you (perhaps at my encouragement) may have found a simple algorithm that seems to work! ha ha

Comment: @גלעדברקן you can test your algo with my case N =13244351359135913 , the result should be 13245111333355994, don't think it will work :)

Comment: It gets the same answer. I have a typo/mistake in the second description of the same "Then we'd place the smallest even number to the right of the first index at the end" should read "Then we'd place the _largest_ even number to the right of the first index at the end." Got it right the first time.

Answer (score 1):

An attempt at a Haskell version of the newer algorithm in A. Webb's answer:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (sort,maximumBy)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

digs :: Integral x => x -> [x]
digs 0 = []
digs x = digs (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]

nextE n
  | e == -1   = "NONE"
  | otherwise = concatMap show $ take (ie' + 1) (M.elems s)
              ++ sort (drop (ie' + 1) (M.elems s')) ++ [r]
 where ds = M.fromList (zip [0..] (digs n))
       rightMost (-1) _  = [(-1,0),(-1,0)]
       rightMost ix   xs
         | even (x) && not (null $ filter (>x) xs) = [(x,ix),(y,iy)]
         | otherwise                               = rightMost (ix - 1) (x:xs)
        where x = fromJust (M.lookup ix ds)
              (y,iy) = minimum . filter ((>= x) . fst) 
                     $ zip xs [ix + 1..M.size ds - 1]
       [(e,ie),(l,il)] = rightMost (M.size ds - 1) []
       s = M.insert il e . M.insert ie l $ ds
       (ir,r) = maximumBy (comparing snd) . M.toList 
              . M.filter even . snd $ M.split ie s
       s' = M.delete ir s
       ie' = fromIntegral ie

main = print (map (\x -> (x,nextE x)) [34722641,8234961,13244351359135913,3579])
```

Output:

```
*Main> main
[(34722641,"34724126"),(8234961,"8236194")
,(13244351359135913,"13245111333355994"),(3579,"NONE")]
(0.02 secs, 563244 bytes)
```

Comment: Referenced answer has now been changed to superior algorithm suggested by גלעד ברקן in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Many has suggested permutation, but for this problem, **dynamic programming with bit-mask** will be another solution.

For dynamic programming, the number of digit can be up to 20 digits, while with normal permutation, it can only be used if N has less than 12 digits. (With time constraint is 1 second , typically for competitive programming)

So the idea is, starting from the most significant digit to the least significant digit, at each step, we try to find the smallest value starting from this digit to the end, at each digit, we have two cases:

- If the number being created is already larger than N for example N is 12345 and currently, we are 23xxx. (We need to find the smallest xxx in this case).
- If the number is not yet larger than N , example N is 12345 and we have 12xxx.

Moreover, at the last digit, we need to determine if the created number is even or odd.

So, we have our simple recursive code:

```
public int cal(boolean[] selected, int[] num, int digit, boolean larger) {
    //Arrays selected will tell which digit in N has already selected, 
    //int digit will tell currently, which digit we are checking
    //boolean larger tells is the number already larger than N

    if (digit + 1 == selected.length) {//Last digit
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
            if (!selected[i]) {
                if (num[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    return -1; // -1 means this is an invalid value
                } else {
                    if (larger) {
                        return num[i];
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int result = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        if (!selected[i]) {
            if (larger) {
                selected[i] = true;
                int val = (int) (num[i] * Math.pow(10, digit) + cal(selected, num, digit + 1, larger));
                if (val != -1 && (result == -1 || result > val)) {
                    result = val;
                }
            } else if (num[i] >= num[digit]) {
                int val = (int) (num[i] * Math.pow(10, digit) + cal(selected, num, digit + 1, num[i] > num[digit]));
                if (val != -1 && (result == -1 || result > val)) {
                    result = val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

From this state, we notice that actually, the `boolean [] selected` can be replaced by a bit-mask value (Read about bitmask here [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29)) , So we can easily represent the state of this recursive by this array `int [mask][larger] dp`

Notice that the parameter `digit` is not necessary as we can easily determine the digit we are checking by counting the number of digit left to be selected.

Finally, we have our solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;


/**
 *
 * @author Trung Pham
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();

        System.out.println(test.largest(2135791357913579L));

    }
    long[][] dp;

    public long largest(long N) {
        String val = "" + N;

        int[] num = new int[val.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = val.charAt(i) - '0';
         //   System.out.println(num[i] + " " + i);
        }
        dp = new long[1 << num.length][2];
        for (long[] a : dp) {
            Arrays.fill(a, -2);
        }
        return cal(0, num, 0);

    }

    public long cal(int mask, int[] num, int larger) {
        //Arrays selected will tell which digit in N has already selected, 
        //int digit will tell currently, which digit we are checking
        //int larger tells is the number already larger than N, if it is 1, it is larger, 0 is not.
        int digit = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (((1 << i) & mask) != 0) {
                digit++;
            }
        }
        if (dp[mask][larger] != -2) {
            return dp[mask][larger];
        }
        if (digit + 1 == num.length) {//Last digit
            //System.out.println(mask + "  " + digit);
            for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                if (((1 << i) & mask) == 0) {
                    if (num[i] % 2 != 0) {
                        return -1; // -1 means this is an invalid value
                    } else {
                        if (larger == 1) {
                            //  System.out.println(num[i] + " " + i);
                            return num[i];
                        } else {
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        long result = -1;
        int l = num.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (((1 << i) & mask) == 0) {
                if (larger == 1) {
                    //System.out.println(num[i]* Math.pow(10,l - digit) + " " + digit);
                    long val = (long) (cal(mask | (1 << i), num, larger));


                    if (val != -1) {
                        val += num[i] * Math.pow(10, l - digit - 1);
                        if (result == -1 || result > val) {
                            result = val;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (num[i] >= num[digit]) {
                    long val = (long) (cal(mask | (1 << i), num, num[i] > num[digit] ? 1 : 0));
                    if (val != -1) {
                        val += num[i] * Math.pow(10, l - digit - 1);
                        if (result == -1 || result > val) {
                            result = val;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dp[mask][larger] = result;
    }
}
```

Notice that this solution can still be improved if you notice that at each digit, we only selected **value from 0 to 9 once**, and the start digit **cannot start with 0**.

Comment: Can you please provide an example number that has a solution and would run too slow with the permutation algorithm?

Comment: @גלעדברקן you can try this 9223372036854775807, which is the max value for a long

Comment: @גלעדברקן the time complexity for permutation is O(n!) which will be  18! in this case, why using dp and bitmask, it will be O (n* (2^(n + 1))) with n is number of digit

Comment: @PhamTrung This computes in about 0.3 msecs in the Clojure implementation in my answer as 9223372036854775870 (have to tweak the digits->long since the answer is larger than a long). That implementation does *not* generate all permutations, just the next one in order (and the next, etc, if not even).

Comment: In fact, in this case the very next permutation in lexicographical order is even, so this just makes a few trips through the digits.

Comment: @A.Webb how your solution is different from generate all permutation? (Sorry I don't know Clojure) so you start to generate from N and move foward one permutation right?

Comment: It only generates the number of permutations between `N` and the first even permutation in order. The algorithm in pseudocode is in the linked Wikipedia article. The complexity to find the next permutation is O(d) if d is the number of digits. I don't know the expected number of permutations you'd have to go through to find an even one in the worst case, but it could be very bad on some inputs, yes.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Only if there is an even permutation nearby. In the worst case performance can be terrible for large inputs.

Comment: @A.Webb As I commented in your answer, for the special case you outlined, I think there is a straightforward solution.

Answer (score -1):

Cases where result will be "NONE":

1. Find the minimum even digit(0, 2, 4, 6, 8) from the given number. Let the digit is x.
2. Take the other digits, sort them in decreasing order. Let's assume this substring is S.

E = S + x (Here + means concatenation)

1. If no even digit is found in step 1, There is no such number.
2. If E, after step 2 is <= N, then there is no such number.

As there are only 5 possible digits those can be placed as the last digit of E, first we consider each of them. Let the current even digit be e. We'll scan N to find if e occurs in N.
If e doesn't occur in N, skip. Otherwise, we remove 1 occurrence of e from N and add it to the end of E. Let's assume the rest digits concatenate to E1.

If e > N % 10, then we need to find the permutation of E1 such that E1 >= N/10 and E1 is minimum. If e <= N %10 then we need a permutation of E1 such that E1 > N/10 and E1 is minimum of every such permutation. So the problem reduces to find a permutation of a number E1, that is greater than or equal to E1 (based on the value of e) and minimum.

You can take it from here and solve this problem as it only needs some careful coding from here to solve the next part of the problem.

Comment: -1: this is wrong. If you put the smallest digit last, you will have a bigger digit in a higher order position, thus resulting in a bigger number. It's obviously wrong even on the second example.